# Which API provides the logo for a cryptocurrency?

Tags: api

I've been searching for an API that returns the logo/image for a cryptocurrency. API's like CoinCap.io and Bittrex don't return this information in the response. Is there any public API which provides the logo for a specific cryptocurrency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use their css class

http://coincap.io/css/spritesheet.css?v=1_6_1

attach it in your html file and call it like that for bitcoin logo:

```
<span class="sprite sprite-bitcoin small_coin_logo"></span>
```

But you have to contact them for copyright measures.

Answer (score 2):

No particular API, but a solution how to get all logos from Coinmarketcap with the correct IDs can be found here: https://github.com/giekaton/cryptocurrency-logos

Comment: For the high quality .png and vector .svg files see this new [Crypto Logos](https://cryptoclothing.cc/crypto-logos) gallery.

Answer (score 1):

New update, seems like CoinCap.io stores their logos here:

[https://assets.coincap.io/assets/icons/{}@2x.png](https://assets.coincap.io/assets/icons/%7B%7D@2x.png)

Just replace the parentheses above with the symbol of the cryptocurrency you are looking for. Example:

https://assets.coincap.io/assets/icons/btc@2x.png

The symbol can be found using the CoinCap.io API

https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets/bitcoin

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "bitcoin",
    "rank": "1",
    "symbol": "BTC",
    "name": "Bitcoin",
    "supply": "17193925.0000000000000000",
    "maxSupply": "21000000.0000000000000000",
    "marketCapUsd": "119179791817.6740161068269075",
    "volumeUsd24Hr": "2928356777.6066665425687196",
    "priceUsd": "6931.5058555666618359",
    "changePercent24Hr": "-0.8101417214350335",
    "vwap24Hr": "7175.0663247679233209"
  },
  "timestamp": 1533581098863
}
```

Docs: https://docs.coincap.io/

Happy coding!

Comment: nice free api, shame a coin like ENS is missing (& i'd speculate other important coin might be missing too)